# rx, looking for something like takeUntilMap

Tags: rxjs

Im trying to achieve following behaviour:

```
//----A--A----A--|-----------------------------------streams
//--B------------B---B--B-------------------------------   


//----A--A----A--B---B--B-----------------------------output
```

in other words: I need to complete A-stream by B-stream and still be able to consume first B item, but I cant find the way to do that.

example `jsfiddle.net/dismedia/qbyy5cvs` we have numbers$ and operators$, I need to scan numbers until operator appears

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
Observable.concat(obsA.takeUntil(obsB), obsB)
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: It wont work like that, we're missing first obsB item that way. (that item which cancels obsA)

Comment: Then why you don't have the first `B` in your output?

Comment: sorry, I mean first B after A A A, 
(second B in stream, (that item which completes obsA) )

Comment: Can you make a demo where the first B is missing?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dismedia/qbyy5cvs/

we have numbers$ and operators$, I need to scan numbers until operator appears

Comment: This demo doesn't do anything

Comment: please, open a console, type numbers, then operator +-*/

in the meantime I will upgrade code to show results in html